# load different version of php using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

my website is using php5.2 by default, but I have php5.3 installed at /opt/5_3/bin/php
Is there any way to tell the website to use php5.3 using .htaccess?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105632/change-php-version-on-server-using-either-htaccess-or-php-ini

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help:

http://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/linux-c85098/php-c37728/manually-set-the-version-of-php-using-an-htaccess-file-a614325.html

The above page doesn't make mention of 5.3 (only 4.4.9, 5.2, and 5.3), but you can probably infer how to do it.